# Integration with multiple derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose I have that:

$$F(x)= \frac{d H(Z)}{dZ}\cdot\frac{d^2 Z}{d x \,d y}$$

Now I want to find

$$\int F(x) \, dx $$

So can I say that

$$\int F(x) \, dx =\int \frac{d H(Z)}{dY} \, dZ\  ?$$

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. Did you look at some examples?